# Changing label's data using textField inout

Tags: uilabel

I want to change the label's text (which is embedded in a tableViewCell) using a textField data (which is embedded outside the tableViewCell). 
Can anyone share the code please using objective-C.

Here is my TableViewCell.h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;

@end
```

Here is my storyboard controller file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController:UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
NSMutableArray *contacts;
}

- (IBAction)leftBtn:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)rightBtn:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)nextBtn:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)SendBtn:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tabV1;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtField;
@end
```

Here I have the button action connection where I should I write the actual code to change the label's data using a text field.

```
- (IBAction)leftBtn:(id)sender {


}
```

Comment: "Please give me code" is not the way this site works ... please show what you've tried., and then explain what your problem is. Use language tags to classify your question.

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to iOS coding and this site as well. Sure Ill share the code.

Comment: @JimHawkins
**This is my TableViewCell.h file where I declared my labels**
TableViewCell : UITableViewCell
IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
IBOutlet UILabel *label2;

Comment: Please read [ask] . Why don't you insert your code in the question? Do you expect everyone reads all the commets? I don't follow your question anymore

Comment: @JimHawkins 
I have added the code. I tried using the below code. still it is giving me error.
      


  cell.label1.text=_txtField.text[indexPath.row];